# Spring AOP point cut error

Tags: java, spring, aop

I am trying to capture all errors that emanate after overriding validate method of spring.

I get the below error

`Pointcut is not well-formed: expecting ')' at character position 135`

I have tried a lot combinations such as putting a ')' before and after and removing but still get the same error. I am learning Spring so not sure if this is exactly the way to implement aop. Could any tell me where I am wrong or correct me

Here is the class which implements the validate method

```
package com.myapplication.validations

public class MyValidate implements Validator{{

        public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return MyValidate.class.equals(clazz);
    }

       public void validate(Object target, MyApplicationErrors errors) {

         //all validations

       }
}
```

Now in my spring application-context.xml I write the following aop

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <bean id="captureErrors"
        class="com.myapplication.aop.CaptureAllErrors" />

    <aop:aspect ref="captureErrors">

        <aop:pointcut id="magicallyCaptureErrors" 
                      expression="execution(* com.myapplication.validations.MyValidate.validate(Object, com.myapplication.allerrors.MyApplicationErrors ))  and args(Object target, com.myapplication.allerrors.MyApplicationErrors errors)" />

        <aop:after-returning pointcut-ref="magicallyCaptureErrors" method="getAllErrors"/>

    </aop:aspect>

    </aop:config>
```

My capture all errors class is as follows

```
package com.myapplication.aop
@Aspect
@Component
public class CaptureAllErrors {


public void getAllErrors(Object target, com.myapplication.allerrors.MyApplicationErrors errors){


log.info(errors.toString());
}

}
```

Comment: I tried removing the "args" part in my application-context.xml. Now I get the following error


I followed your advise and removed the "args" part in application-context.xml. Now I get the following error WebApplicationObjectSupport instance [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver@1a9ca78] does not run in a WebApplicationContext but in: org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@1e57e8f: startup date [Fri Apr 12 12:09:05 EDT 2013]; root of context hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

Character 135 of your expression starts here:

```
and args(Object target
               ^
```

The `args()` pointcut should list the types of the parameters, not the type and the name. So try this instead:

```
and args(Object, MyApplicationErrors)
```

It's also worth pointing out that the entire `args()` expression is redundant, since the `execution()` pointcut specifies the required signature of the method parameters as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an extra ')' at 135 which will close the Point cut Prematurely

validate(Object, com.myapplication.allerrors.MyApplicationErrors )')'

expression="execution(* com.myapplication.validations.MyValidate.validate(Object, com.myapplication.allerrors.MyApplicationErrors )**)**  and args(Object target, com.myapplication.allerrors.MyApplicationErrors errors)"

Once you remove it, you will be fine.